# ANdroid phone downloading app(s) when connecting to internet

Tags: applications, malware

I have a android phone. It was working fine. But then it started downloading file which name's something like "com.xxx.xxx.xxx" the exact name I dont remember so I use letter `x`. After the file gets downloaded, gaming apps start downloading and start running.

I reinstall android, but the problem still persists. Any help will be highly appreciated. Android version is 5.1

Comment: please specify phone model and name.

Comment: @RahulGopi I reinstalled android. The only thing I did was to update `WhatsApp`. And nothing I did after reinstalling `Android`

Comment: @RahulGopi model is this http://www.qmobile.com.pk/product/i1/

Comment: Please check data usage of each apps and analyze.  Provide data and wifi to those apps which you think that are secure and useful.

Comment: @RahulGopi there are only four apps and are all from google necessary for andriod to function. as I said I have nt installed any application

Comment: If possible, try to get the full filename to make it easier to analyze. You can try by taking a screenshot when it happens (on some device, it's by pressing and holding power+vol down buttons). Your device might have a malware ([some devices are proven to have malware pre-installed](http://thehackernews.com/2016/11/hacking-android-smartphone.html))